# Triangular repdigits

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, digits

I would like to know whether $55$, $66$ and $666$ are the only triangular numbers that are repdigits, i.e., numbers at least $10$ whose digits w.r.t. base 10 all agree.

In more sophisticated terms, I am asking about solutions of the equation
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{d}{9}(10^k-1)$$
where $k \geq 2$ and $n$ are positive integers and $d \in \{1,2, \dots, 9\}$.

Here are some quick ideas:

Considering the remainder of triangular numbers modulo 100 yields that this can only work for $d \in \{1,5,6\}$. I only looked into the case $d = 5$ in greater detail. Then, the equation above can be rephrased as
$$(6n+3)^2 = 4\cdot10^{k+1}-31.$$
If $k$ is odd, there are no solutions as $31$ is no difference of two squares. (Alternatively, use that the RHS is $\equiv 6 \ (\text{mod. } 11)$, but $6$ is a quadratic nonresidue of $11$.)

For $k$ even, we would like to find all solutions to the Pell-like equation
$$x^2 - 10y^2 = -31$$
where $y$ is twice a power of $10$. Two such solutions are given by $(x_0,y_0) = (3,2)$ and $(x_0', y_0') = (63,20)$. The theory of Pell's equation yields that all solutions of this equation are given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}19 & 60 \\
6 & 19\end{pmatrix}^m \ \textbf{v}$$
where $m \geq 0$ and $\textbf{v} = (x_0, y_0)^{T}$ or $\textbf{v} = (x_0', y_0')^{T}$. But does this really help to prove that none of these has the property that the second component is twice a power of ten unless $m=0$?

Comment: Instead of thinking about Pell equations, it makes more sense to think of $10^{k+1}$ as either $y^3$, $10 y^3$, or $100 y^3$, and then one has a Thue equation for which there are effective methods for finding all solutions. Mike Bennett can solve these in his sleep.

Comment: A proof that only $55$, $66$, and $666$ qualify is offered for inspection at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Repdigit_Triangular_Numbers – more formal publications are David W. Ballew and Ronald C. Weger, Triangular Numbers with Repeated Digits, Proc. S. D. Acad. Sci., Vol. 51 (1972), pp. 52-55; David W. Ballew and Ronald C. Weger, Repdigit triangular numbers, J. Rec. Math., Vol. 8, No. 2 (1975-76), pp. 96-98.

Comment: I do not believe these "proofs" are correct. For the digit $5$, they try to argue that no square ends in $4\dots 41$ for sufficiently many fours, but any number $\equiv 1 (8)$ is a quadratic residue modulo any power of $2$, and any number $\equiv 1 (5)$ is  a quadratic residue modulo any power of $5$. Thus there are square numbers ending in $4\dots 41$ with arbitrarily many fours.

Comment: E.g., $32021^2=1025344441$.

Comment: Yes, that's a big hole in those arguments. By the way, had you included @Gerry in your comment, then I would have been notified of it.

Comment: They don't argue that no square *ends in* $4\ldots 41$ but that no square (other than 441) *is of the form* $4\ldots 41$.

Comment: But yes, their calculations to support that claim do seem to be erroneous.

Comment: @user523984: Why do you call it [True equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation)? It looks more like [Mordell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve) to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [user523984](https://mathoverflow.net/users/523984/user523984)'s suggestion in the comments:

From triangle = repdigit $$\frac{k(k+1)}2 = \frac{d(10^j-1)}9$$ we get $$k = \frac{-1 \pm \frac13 \sqrt{9 + 8d(10^j-1)}}{2}$$ so we require $9 + 8d(10^j-1) = y^2$.

Case-splitting on $j = 3m + i$ we get $y^2 = 8d \cdot 10^i (10^m)^3 + (9 - 8d)$. Substitute $x = 10^m$, $c = 8d \cdot 10^i$ and put into Weierstrass form as $y'^2 = x'^3 + (9 - 8d)c^2$ with $y' = cy$, $x' = cx$. Then we can ask a CAS to find integral points and filter to relevant ones.

For example, in Sage:

```
# Elliptic curves to solve the triangular repdigit problem
for d in range(1, 10):
    for i in range(3):
        c = 8 * d * 10^i
        ec = EllipticCurve([0, 0, 0, 0, (9 - 8*d)*c^2])
        for xprime, yprime, _ in ec.integral_points():
            if xprime % c == 0 and yprime % c == 0:
                x, y = xprime // c, yprime // c
                # We require x to be a power of 10
                if x == 0:
                    continue

                m = int(log(x) / log(10) + 0.5)
                if x == 10^m:
                    k = (abs(y) / 3 - 1) / 2
                    rep = d * (10^(3*m+i) - 1) / 9
                    if rep > 0:
                        print(k, rep)

print("Search complete")
```

[Run this online at sagecell.sagemath.org](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1UtFuglAMfTfxH040Sy7IFDVLdIl7WfYFe9jDMg1CxRuByy7g8O_XbqDLlAZCue3pOW3vEC9JovNShwgre6QCpUFhkiOh3PNrdZDFVRJYWMojHesSuTXbhNJ-b2csIugMlnNITT1Mfeex3wObxPQlNm_PxUKssIDLWJcRa32JkIRaQc-iR737Hs6PWuIeCzdy3HA9-3AuQKGrc6tT8nBqvhuhp3Css5JiGySb3LBbqL9SxPSugeJOpK3gI8iipsz57B9IrGYu1tuAJxOELfnPzzVgiDfiOX5W2hJqmfSWECA3X2RhdjyMa4yo6xLwM0yTlTqrqN-7jqesjltWiYlV7WACcXhHGMEfPzjdZLyVtIPvwDVVsC3USQrOeR9TcWa3s_nScL4smnnXau6mI-20mOVtDIsQ2FNny2I8Zm7s4EmqI73_HgxeKbDhnqeS5gmVNHC-ASrZrEM=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

It turns out that Ballew and Weger's result is correct, even though their argument does appear to have some calculation errors (including, but not limited to, an apparent belief that $0$ cannot be a digit in $y$).

Comment: Btw, "power of 10" can be tested without floating point arithmetic (computing log's etc.) via `x == 10^valuation(x,10)`.